# JSP page only receives the first arrayList

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, taglib

In jsp page, it is printing only the function which is accessed first. If function-1 is accessed first, function-2 is not be printed. And if Function-2 is accessed first, Function-1 is not printed. Any suggestions please.

Controller:

```
populateTf(tfCount, request, response);
populateSa(saCount, request, response);

response.sendRedirect("testPage.jsp");

//FUNCTION-1
void populateTf(int tfCount, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){       
    ArrayList<TF> tfList = new ArrayList<TF>();

    String field1 = request.getParamter("xyz");
    String field2 = request.getParamter("xyz");
    String field3 = request.getParamter("xyz");

    tfList.add(new TF(field1, field2, field3));

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("tfList", tfList);
}

//FUNCTION-2
void populateSa(int saCount, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){       
    ArrayList<SA> saList = new ArrayList<SA>();

    String field1 = request.getParamter("xyz");

    saList.add(new SA(field1));

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("saList", saList);
}
```

Bussiness Objects:

```
public class TF{
    private String field1, field2, field3;
    public TrueFalse(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }
    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
}    

public class SA{
   private String field1;
   public ShortAnswer(String field1) {
      this.field1 = field1;
   }
   /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */ 
}
```

Here is the JSP page:

```
<table>      
        <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.tfList}" var="tf">
        <tr>
                <td>${tf.field1}</td>
                <td>${tf.field2}</td>
                <td>${tf.field3}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>

<table>         
        <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.saList}" var="sa">
        <tr>
                <td>${sa.field1}</td>               
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of calling `request.getSession()` twice, make a global var to hold the session in your servlet, and call `request.getSession()` only once.  I also don't see the need to pass request and response to those two functions.

```
private HttpSession session = null;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    session = request.getSession();
    ....
    populateTf(tfCount);
    populateSa(saCount);
    ....
}

private void populateTf(int tfCount)
{       
    ArrayList<TF> tfList = new ArrayList<TF>();

    .... //where is field1, field2, field3 coming from anyway?

    tfList.add(new TF(field1, field2, field3));

    session.setAttribute("tfList", tfList);
}

private void populateSa(int saCount)
{       
    ArrayList<SA> saList = new ArrayList<SA>();

    .... //where is field1 coming from anyway?

    saList.add(new SA(field1));

    session.setAttribute("saList", saList);
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. but still not working. Getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: @fhaider, Well, assuming that its from `session` being `null` still when you call `session.setAttribute` its because you have to do `session = request.getSession();` at the actual point of entry. I assumed that was your `doGet`. It could be your `doPost` if you're doing POST. It could be you're using some strange framework and its something else. I don't know. You basically posted pseudo-code, so you're going to have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Null pointer solved. Still having the previous problem. Only printing the first arrayList. I've added field1, field2 and field3 where they were coming from.